# Image Caching Problem

Tags: iphone

I am Storing the Image taken from UIImagePickerController and saving in the Directory
like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                  [paths objectAtIndex:0], 1.jpg];
[imgData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

When iam Retrieving the image from the path and display in TableView it work for 1 or 2 times
then application crash and error occurs is "memory urgent" 
also used code for retrieving image in UIIMageView like [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]
but not working help.
so How to handle the image caching?

Comment: the crash is not happening because of your write to disk here.  This is fine, (except for the 1.jpg not in a NSString).  PLease post the code on how you retrieve and use it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just running out of memory, and probably not in the code you've shared.

Image files are memory-hungry, especially if they are larger than the resolution of the screen.

Read all about [UIImagePickerController, UIImage, Memory and More!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more) for more detail about the memory cost of images and ways to work around that.